# XPath Selector by Class

Tags: php, css, xpath

How do I select the text inside of the Stage One div. It has a unique name of "field-name-field-stage-one". I want to echo the summary.

Link to website: http://fosterinnovationculture.com/drupalc/?q=node/17

This is what I have so far:

```
$doc = new DomDocument;
$some_link = 'http://fosterinnovationculture.com/drupalc/?q=node/17';
$tagName = 'div';
$attrName = 'class';
$attrValue = 'field-name-field-stage-one';

$doc->validateOnParse = true;
$doc->loadHtml(file_get_contents($some_link));

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("/html/body//div[contains(@class,'$attrValue')]");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the inner element with `field-item` class and extract the `nodeValue` value:

```
$elements = $xpath->query("/html/body//div[contains(@class,'$attrValue')]/div[contains(@class, 'field-item')]");
print_r($elements[0]->nodeValue);
```

Prints:

```
The survey results show that your organization is ‘interested’ in design-led innovation, which is stage 1 in our framework.

‘Interested’ means that some people in the organization are noticing design contributions and the methods designers use. Some individuals are experiencing success in a few projects.  The use of design methods is ad hoc, unintentional and happening at a grass roots level. Design continues to be perceived as an added cost to the development process. As a result, there is little executive support or buy-in.
```

Comment: Now if I want to store the text in a variable is it as easy as `$stage = $elements[0]->nodeValue;` ?